# String.Replace() will not change the source string of the variable

Tags: c#

I have the following code inside my c# application:-

```
 string[] excludechar = { "|", "\\", "\"", "'", "/", "[", " ]", ":", "<", " >", "+", "=", ",", ";", "?", "*", " @" };
 var currentgroupname = curItemSiteName;
 for (int i = 0; i < excludechar.Length; i++)
       {
         if (currentgroupname.Contains(excludechar[i]))
             currentgroupname.Replace(excludechar[i], "");       
       }
 site.RootWeb.SiteGroups.Add(currentgroupname)
```

now in my abive code the `currentgroupname` variable which i am passing inside the `.ADD` function will have all the special characters i have replaced inside my for loop. so can anyone adivce if i can modify my code so the .Replace will be actually replacing the original string of the `currentgroupname` ...

Comment: maybe currentgroupname = currentgroupname.Replace(excludechar[i], "");

Comment: `currentgroupname = currentgroupname.Replace(...);`  As always, check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: strings are immutable. You'll just be creating a new string, and replacing your old string with the new one (following ^)

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually assigning the "replaced" string to `currentgroupname`

```
 string[] excludechar = { "|", "\\", "\"", "'", "/", "[", " ]", ":", "<", " >", "+", "=", ",", ";", "?", "*", " @" };
 var currentgroupname = curItemSiteName;
 for (int i = 0; i < excludechar.Length; i++)
       {
         if (currentgroupname.Contains(excludechar[i]))
             currentgroupname = currentgroupname.Replace(excludechar[i], "");       
       }
 site.RootWeb.SiteGroups.Add(currentgroupname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier with some `regex?`

```
var input = "<>+--!I/have:many@invalid\\|\\characters";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\W", "");
Console.Write(result); //Ihavemanyinvalidcharacters
```

Don't forget the using:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```